# IDE Displaying Error when [( Is Used in An Array Variable

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I am using `Aptana Studio 3` and it's highlighting the square brackets as a potential error. It inteferes with my coding because I keep thinking that am messing somewhere. The code is running well and no error is displayed on the console. How do I fix it?

```
$series_data[] = array(
    'name' => 'Brands', 
    'colorByPoint' => true,  
    'data'=> array(
        ['name' => 'Nairobi, KE', 'y' => 56.33],
        ['name'=> 'Kisumu, KE', 'y'=>64.03 ],
        ['name'=> 'New Yorm, USA', 'y'=>44.03 ]
```

The error is displayed between ( and [ as below:

```
data=array([
```

Comment: And why exactly is this tagged jquery, json and codeigniter?

Comment: you missed a few brackeds

Comment: The `[...]` array syntax is only valid in PHP 5.4 and higher, so possibly your IDE is configured to expect PHP 5.3 syntax? Check the IDE's config. Also, can I recommend that you be a bit more consistent in which array syntax you use? There's nothing inherently wrong with mixing between `array(...)` and `[...]` notations, but it does make the code harder to read.

Comment: And you forgot to include this as an answer. @Simba

Comment: @O'Brien Okay, I've added it as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[...]` array syntax is only valid in PHP 5.4 and higher, so possibly the problem is that your IDE is configured to expect PHP 5.3 syntax? Check the IDE's config.

Also, can I recommend that you be a bit more consistent in which array syntax you use? There's nothing inherently wrong with mixing between `array(...)` and `[...]` notations, but it does make the code harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

Check this 
you forgot to use `)`

```
$series_data[] = array(
'name' => 'Brands', 
'colorByPoint' => true,  
'data'=> array(
    ['name' => 'Nairobi, KE', 'y' => 56.33],
    ['name'=> 'Kisumu, KE', 'y'=>64.03 ],
    ['name'=> 'New Yorm, USA', 'y'=>44.03 ]
    )
            );
```

[image]

Comment: In the question he says *"The code is running well and no error is displayed"*, so I would guess that actually he has got the closing brackets correct already, but didn't copy them into the question.